# Weed out inaccurate information from 2 million records

Tags: data-request, tool-request, internet, geocoding

I have a database with about two million entries (!), relating IP ranges to locations. Unfortunately, a lot of the data is overlapping, so that every IP produces multiple hits (about two or three. Of these, only one is within an acceptable range of error. I have tried with about 10 IPs, and it seems the last one is always the most accurate, but I would like to try with more, about a thousand before making such a general rule and weeding out stuff by it.

Is there anywhere I can get such a massive number of accurate IP addresses, complete with location information?

Is there a better way of cleaning this data?

Comment: This doesn't seem especially like it relates to open data. I reckon you'd do better with your request for data wrangling help on Stack Overflow. If you're after a source for IP/location data then this is potentially the right place, but the question would need an edit.

Comment: There are a lot of things that can wrong with GeoIP -- IP blocks get reassigned, so can change over time.  You also have delegation, so a larger block might be assigned to one location and a subnet that's somewhere else.  (quite common within companies with multiple branches that have an older class B)

Comment: Oh ... and this would probably be more on-topic if you were asking about accurate GeoIP databases that you could use to verify / validate your data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP Geocoding Data Sources and/or APIs](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/ip-geocoding-data-sources-and-or-apis)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/open-city/dedupe. I haven't used it, but looks like it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you do want to simply take the final entry for each geography, perhaps import your data set into any SQL database and use the `LAST` command like this

```
SELECT LAST( ip_column ) , geography_name FROM tablename GROUP BY geography_name
```

[click here for a more thorough explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_last.asp)

SQL databases should be able to handle two million records without a problem, even on an older laptop :)