# IP Geocoding Data Sources and/or APIs

Tags: data-request, geocoding, api

I am looking for IP address to geocoding data sources and/or APIs. Open to any formats, and the main concern is the quality, depth, and freshness of the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three sources that may be helpful:

- The answer on Stack Overflow on how to [Geocode an IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232516/geocode-an-ip-address)
- [Free GEOIP](http://freegeoip.net/) has a RESTful API for this specific task
- The [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup?csw=1)
- A [geolocation XML API](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) from PInfoDB

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think the Google Map API and IPInfoDB qualify as open data :-)

Comment: PInfoDB requires registration for use of the API, but for the same reasons many sites do in collecting metrics, rather than charging for the service. I included Google Map API only as a secondary component that may help @blunders to map the results of any earlier query.

Comment: They seem (but I am not 100% sure) to use data from http://lite.ip2location.com/databases . These databases come either with a commercial license or with a free license. The free license says `The LITE edition is an open-source version of database with limited accuracy & number of records compares to commercial release. It is free for personal or commercial use with attribution required`. So I was wrong, IPInfoDB seems to qualify as open data indeed :-)

Answer (score 4):

For a project I use the [GeoLite City](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) download from [MaxMind](http://dev.maxmind.com/). The license is "[Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)."

This file is usually updated every month, so I have a script that checks if the file has been updated and only downloads/unzips if it has:

```
wget -N http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
```

I choose the binary file, and not the CSV, because there is a nice python library to load this data and then do the lookups: [pygeoip](http://pythonhosted.org//pygeoip/). For thousands of IP addresses, I found this process **much** faster than sending each IP address to an external web API.

A python snippet to load the IP table and then do a lookup:

```
import pygeoip
gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoLiteCity.dat')
print gi.record_by_addr('64.233.161.99')
```

provides a JSON output like this:

```
 {'city': u'Mountain View', 'region_name': u'CA', 'area_code': 650, 'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'dma_code': 807, 'metro_code': 'San Francisco, CA', 'country_code3': 'USA', 'latitude': 37.41919999999999, 'postal_code': u'94043', 'longitude': -122.0574, 'country_code': 'US', 'country_name': 'United States', 'continent': 'NA'}
```

Answer (score 3):

*(Just to add details to the second list item in Jeanne's answer)*

[freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net/) is a community-built IP geocoding platform.

Database files are [downloaded automatically by the updatedb script from the blog.freegeoip.net domain](https://github.com/fiorix/freegeoip/blob/master/db/updatedb#L128) and according to [their blog](http://blog.freegeoip.net/2013/06/all-cities-in-the-world.html) the data actually comes from the [Geolite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) databases which are disctributed under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.

In addition:

- The engine itself is open source
- There is even a free hosted API (with hourly limits)

Answer (score 3):

Three more IP geolocation APIs/Datasets I can suggest:

[www.ip2location.com  - free version for non-commercial use](http://www.ip2location.com/)

[www.hostip.info - crowdsourced dataset and API](http://www.hostip.info/)

[dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ - free IP geolocation dataset](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/)