# Hong Kong geocoding data

Tags: data-request, geocoding

I would like to obtain Hong Kong data for geocoding, where can I get it in addition to OSM and Geonames?

I use postgresql and postgis as my database, and the TIGER dataset in postgis, which is a product of the US Census Bureau. This was created to support the US Constitution's requirement for a decennial census to support redistricting in the US House of Representatives. Their mandate only covers US states, commonwealths, territories, and possessions. And Hong Kong is not one of these.

I have downloaded Geonames data from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/, but these data are very incomplete.

Then I downloaded OSM data from http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html. But its SHP file looks like it has no information about coordinates and zip code, and I don't know how to open or process the other two format files.

Comment: Did you see [this related question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/ip-geocoding-data-sources-and-or-apis?rq=1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using [Mapzen](https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/) to download Hong Kong map data. The source is from OSM but it includes some name tags. Hope they are helpful.

Not exactly what you are looking for, but I have toyed the data [here](https://github.com/bmkor/hk_osm_map).

Answer (score 0):

Hong Kong is fully covered by [Batch Geocoding](https://csv2geo.com) tool called CSV2GEO. They carry manual/file based input as well as API. You can review their prices [here](https://csv2geo.com/price) which include free geocoding.
Example below shows how USA embassy with address 26 Garden Rd, Central, Hong Kong is located by CSV2GEO interactive map.
[image]

Disclaimer: I founded CSV2GEO.